# How to Prevent Caching When using PDF Streaming with Acrobar Reader 10.0 (HTTP1.0/HTTP1.1)

Tags: caching, pdf, header, acrobat

I was trying to find a way to prevent browsers from caching PDF that is being loaded using a streaming methods.

FireFox and Chorme deals just fine with the following headers and doesn't cache any pdf file:

Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache, no-store");
Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
Response.AddHeader("Expires", "-1");

Although, IE 7 (with acrobat reader 9.4.1) works only with the following headers and prevent the caching of the PDF doc:

Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache, no-store");
Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "private, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
Response.AddHeader("Expires", "-1");

When i was trying to use IE 7 with Acrobat Reader 10, the above header didn't make any different and cached the PDF no matter what i tried.

When i am trying to put Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, the pdf was not loaded at all.
According to my understanding, IE use the cache mechanism to load the PDF documents.

Is there anyone familiar with a global or specific way (by using other headers for example) that can help prevent caching of PDF documents?

Answer (score 7):

Add a random number to the URL, either in the path or in the query string. That way, it'll download the file every time. You could also change the number only, if the file has changed, for example using the mtime of the file.

PHP (since everybody understands that, even if nobody likes it):

```
 <a href="document.pdf?buster=<?= time() ?>">Download PDF</a>
```

Comment: This is most definately an elegant work-around for this kind of issue.

Comment: This will not work if pdf on server has spaces in the name.

Answer (score 1):

This issue of showing PDF (and other document types) inline with the use of the no-cache header has been filed as a bug to Microsoft: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316431. IE uses its own caching mechanism when reading PDFs inline.

Unfortunately, the folks at M$ said this "works as designed" and users should not use the no-cache header... go figure.

You could try VSU's idea of using a Java PDF reader... I may go this route too.

Answer (score 0):

Controlling the cache settings down the pipe is not fool proof. The alternative is to encode the realtime and date in the file name of the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the time date into the filename of the PDF so that each time a request is made the filename is unique.

`Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=somename" + CurrentDate() + Currenttime() ".pdf"`

CurrentDate adn CurrentTime are imaginary functions. You need to write that code.

Comment: by sending this header, the browser ask me to download the file. when i tried to put "inline" instead of "attachment" it's still being saved into the cache. any suggestion about how can i stream the pdf documents without caching it ?

Comment: I thought the reason you did not want the PDF document to be cached was to ensure that a fresh PDF was generated each time. Now, I realize that you want to prevent it from being stored in the client. Well, you can create a Java applet that downloads the PDF and displays its and when the user is finished with it deletes it. The server could encrypt it and the applet could do decrypt for extra safety. Here is an example of our Java PDF viewer that can display the PDF inside a web page http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=195&t=A_Java_PDF_Web_Viewer_-_Powered_By_PDFOne_(for_Java_trade;)

Comment: Hi,

thanks for your response.

i'm searching for a sulotion which doesn not includes any 3rd parties or an external code. just trying to realize why is the browser (or the acrobat plugin) ignores the specified headers.

Thanks in advance for your answer.